# Calling a static method of a class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm attempting to call a static class method via reflection and get its return value as follows:

```
private SA GetData()
{
    Type type = Type.GetType("SA010");

    Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetSA");

    return (SA)methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

Here's the class and method I'm calling:

```
public class SA010
{
    public static SA GetSA()
    {
        //do stuff
        return SA.
    }
}
```

The problem is i receive a null reference exception on the 'type' variable. GetData() and SA010.GetSA() are in the same namespace.

Any ideas why i might get this error, something to do with it being static maybe?

Comment: Firstly, why are you creating an *instance* when you're trying to call a static method? You should pass in `null` as the first argument to `Invoke`. However, the problem is really that `Type.GetType()` needs the namespace-qualified name. So you want `Type.GetType("My.Namespace.SA10")`. If `SA10` is in a different *assembly* (which isn't the same concept as namespace) you'll need to specify that too.

Comment: @stuartd: Not a problem: "The search includes public static and public instance methods."

Comment: If you're hard-coding both the type and the method name though, why are you using reflection at all? Does your real code receive both of those dynamically? If so, are you able to change the caller to pass in the fully-qualified type name?

Comment: Thanks for checking but this was modified to just highlight the issue, it infact loops over a string[] that contains class names that all have the same method.

Comment: Right, so are those class names fully qualified? Whenever you ask a question, think about the natural questions that other people will ask in order to try to help you - provide a [mcve] which is representative of what you're trying to achieve, but without anything else that's irrelevant to the problem itself.

Comment: It's all working now and I've accepted an answer, the class names are now fully qualified and that works fine. I'll try a be more specific next time :)

Comment: Yup - bear in mind that the primary goal of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of high quality questions and answers. Helping the user who happened to run into a problem is a secondary (though still important) aspect. That perspective can radically change how you view questions on SO :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your main problem is you need to specify the full namespace of SA010 when using GetType.

```
Type type = Type.GetType("SomeNamespace.SA010");
```

However if you are not dynamicly generating the name a easier solution is use `typeof`, this does not require you to entire the namespace in if the type is already within scope.

```
Type type = typeof(SA010);
```

2nd issue you will run in to once you fix the type, if a method is static you don't create a instance of it, you just pass `null` in for the instance for the `Invoke` call.

```
private SA GetData()
{
    Type type = typeof(SA010);

    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("GetSA");

    return (SA)methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: While I agree with that, you've missed  the problem the OP has actually reported - `type` is null, and your code won't help with that.

Comment: Refresh, it is fixed

Comment: Well the first snippet isn't - given that that's the *main* problem the OP is facing, I'd personally address that issue first... the "you don't need an instance" is really secondary.

Comment: It's also quite likely that simple typeof can be used. And if type is in another assembly- you need assembly qualified name.

Comment: Refresh again, I have done a more major rewrite focusing on the type issue

Comment: Right - much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Type type = typeof(SA010);
```

instead of

```
Type type = Type.GetType("SA010");
```

it worked for me