# Using the instance number of a for loop as part of the call name for a function

Tags: c#, winforms, function, events, call

This is probably a silly question, but I'd like to understand how to do this more efficiently.

I have this code example here:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string callName = "someFunction";
    for(int i = 0; i<2;i++)
    {
        callName = callName + Convert.ToString(i);
        //call callName function
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}

public static void someFunction1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
public static void someFunction2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

I'd like to create the callname for the functions based on the for loop's index.

Edit:

I might not completely understand how to use EventListeners properly. To better illustrate the problem I'm having with windows forms, I am making a windows-form that has a a bunch of Panels in it within a Panel[,].  I'd like to add action listeners to each individual panel using the index of my loops.

```
public test()
{
    Panel[,] board = new Panel[2, 2];
    bool colorChange = true;
    //Create checkered panels
    for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
        {
            if (colorChange)
            {
                Panel currentPanel = CreatePanel(column * 100, row * 100 + 25, 100, 100, 255, 255, 255);
                board[column, row] = currentPanel;
                colorChange = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Panel currentPanel = CreatePanel(column * 100, row * 100 + 25, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0);
                board[column, row] = currentPanel;
                colorChange = true;
            }
        }
        colorChange = !colorChange;
    }
    //unpack panels add controls to the form
    for (int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(board[column, row]);
        }
    }
    //Could for loop here... But what about event?
    board[0, 0].Click += new EventHandler(asd); //??
}

private void asd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi");
}
//Is there a better way to handle this part??
private void asd2(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hi2");
}

public static Panel CreatePanel(int x, int y, int width, int height, int r, int g, int b)
{
    Panel myPanel = new Panel();
    myPanel.Location = new Point(x, y);
    myPanel.Size = new Size(width, height);
    int[] rgb = { r, g, b };
    myPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
    myPanel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    myPanel.Show();
    return myPanel;
}
```

Comment: The magic word you are looking for is `Action`.

Comment: This would be better accomplished by a single `someFunction(int i)` and then doing `if` or `switch` in the body. Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: @AshleyPillay To see if I can consolidate some code that I have written.

Comment: check reflection e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042478/calling-a-static-method-of-a-class-using-reflection

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you post more code & show us what you're really trying to do?

Comment: btw, `callName=callName+Convert.ToString(i);` could be replaced by `callName=callName+i;`

Comment: If those 2 methods exist in same class, just use `var c = new ClassName();` and then `typeof(c).GetMethod("someFunction" + i.ToString()).Invoke(c);` inside for loop.

Comment: Instead of this weird approach, why don't you pass the int-parameter to a single method=

Comment: :S sorry guys I was just wondering about it with a string like so. I recognize that i can pass an int argument through a function, but im trying to make different method calls sync up in that fashion in case I do other bad habits lol

Comment: @Jamin using reflection to handle your program flow (dynamically decide which parts of your code should be called during runtime instead of compile time) is *often* not the good approach. It is hardly maintainable, and thus, if you can avoid it, is considered bad practice. What you are asking is indeed something that could be a bad habit ;)

Comment: Check this also http://szumiato.pl/2016/07/05/invoking-methods-dynamically-in-c-examples-and-benchmarks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most questions which lead to a reflection approach are [XY-problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You ask for X but you actually want Y and think you need X. I'm sure this is one.

Why you don't simply implement a single method with a paramater?

```
public static void PrintNumber(int number)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Then you can call it in your loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    PrintNumber(i);
}
```

---

If you really need the reflection approach:

```
Type t = typeof(Program);
var methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("someFunction"))
    .ToArray();

for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
{
    MethodInfo method = methods.Single(m => m.Name == "someFunction" + i);
    method.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: I updated with more narrowing question please see thanks

Comment: @Jamin: i have added the reflection approach

Comment: Wow that is pretty sweet. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be reflection, and would achieve what you want :

```
class Program
{
    public static void someFunction1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
    }

    public static void someFunction2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var functionList = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Delegate>() {
            { nameof(someFunction1), new Action(() => someFunction1()) },
            { nameof(someFunction2), new Action(() => someFunction2()) },
        };

        string callNameBase = "someFunction";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            string callName = callNameBase + i.ToString();

            functionList[callName].DynamicInvoke();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

(NB : I fixed the indices which were wrong with your example : 1, 2 against 0, 1, and also the way you constructed the name of the function)

---

However, as already noted, there might better practices to achieve what you want.

Maybe a Strategy Pattern of some sort.

But since we don't know what you want to achieve exactly, it's hard to advise you better.

---

### **EDIT** after your detailed question:

Apparently, you want one handler for half of your panels, and another handler for the other half. Then you can just attach the correct event handler during their creation :

```
    for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
    {
        if (colorChange)
        {
            Panel currentPanel = CreatePanel(column * 100, row * 100 + 25, 100, 100, 255, 255, 255);
            board[column, row] = currentPanel;
            colorChange = false;
            board[column, row].Click += new EventHandler(asd); // here
        }
        else
        {
            Panel currentPanel = CreatePanel(column * 100, row * 100 + 25, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0);
            board[column, row] = currentPanel;
            colorChange = true;
            board[column, row].Click += new EventHandler(asd2); // and here
        }
    }
```

(hope I guessed correctly)

Comment: NB : posted that just before your edit with more details

Comment: I updated my original post to demonstrate a clearer idea of what my problem is.  Although you guys answered what I'm looking for I feel as though I may be missing something important with EventListeners. And this may very well be a XY problem as @Tim Schmelter mentioned

Comment: @Jamin : I edited my answer and provided you with a more specific answer for your case. Indeed the solution should be much more simple ! (If I guessed what you want correctly)

Comment: I am actually looking for more than 2 possible events, like each panel has an event. Thank you for showing me this way of doing it, it's very useful too!