# Is it possible to run a static method using getType function in C#?

Tags: c#, class, static-methods, gettype

I have a base class and some derived classes that have some static methods. Is it possible to run static method if I know only the object of base class.

Ive tried typeof and getType methods to do it but as I realised they give only the Type. I know that my issue can be solved by comparing Type with my classes and finally it will work fine. But I hope that better pattern exists.

```
Type type = building.GetType();
type.arrangeCeremony(); // arrange ceremony is public static method in all derived classes
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You can do this with reflection, but why are they static in the first place, if you need to call them like this?

Comment: x-y. Please explain, what you are trying to do with this. I am pretty confident there is a (better) solution.

Comment: If you know the object of base class, that means it has instance and static function is not needed anymore. You should extract `ArrangeCeremony()` into an interface and assign it to the base class, now all derived classes implements that too. Then you can call `ArrangeCeremony()` as long as you have object of such base class.

Comment: Please show us more code, and I'm pretty sure someone can explain how to do this the "proper" way

Comment: ^^ This. Especially explain, _why_ that method is `static`. Is this a hard requirement?

Comment: As your question stands, it is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41042478/calling-a-static-method-of-a-class-using-reflection or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384976/calling-a-static-method-using-a-type - the fact your instance is a derived type is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! yeah, I know about polymorphism. I can't use it because my stupid task in the university. I need to have static method in each class, so I can't use virtual or interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the operation depends on the type: the *most reasonable* way to implement that is simply: polymorphism.

So: make the method non-static and move it to a base-type, as either `virtual` or `abstract`, and then `override` it in the sub-types. Then you don't need to ask the building what type it is: you *just use polymorphism*

```cs
building.ArrangeCeremony();

abstract class SomeBase {
    public abstract void ArrangeCeremony();
}
class SomeConcrete : SomeBase {
    public override void ArrangeCeremony() { /* code here */ }
}
```

If not all types can sensibly implement the method, then perhaps create an `interface`, or have the method declared at some sensible intermediate type level, and use a type test:

```cs
if (building is ICeremonial ceremonial)
{
    ceremonial.ArrangeCeremony();
}

class SomeBase { }
interface ICeremonial {
    void ArrangeCeremony();
}
class SomeConcrete : SomeBase, ICeremonial {
    public void ArrangeCeremony() { /* code here */ }
}
```

or

```cs
if (building is Ceremonial ceremonial)
{
    ceremonial.ArrangeCeremony();
}

class SomeBase { }
abstract class Ceremonial : SomeBase {
    public abstract void ArrangeCeremony();
}
class SomeConcrete : Ceremonial {
    public override void ArrangeCeremony() { /* code here */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! yeah, I know about polymorphism. I can't use it because my stupid task in the university. I need to have static method in each class, so I can't use virtual

Comment: @a11ex could each polymorphic override just *call* the relevant static method?

Comment: wow
great idea 
thank you